# How to hide warnings from Azure PowerShell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

Am getting warnings when i invoke some azure commandlets.
Example:

```
Get-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $storageName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -verbose:$false

New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $storageName -Location $storageLocation -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -verbose:$false
```

**WARNING**: GeoReplicationEnabled property will be deprecated in a future release of Azure PowerShell. The value will be merged into the AccountType property.

Please note: I have been using $verbose:False to avoid such messages from the invocation. But could not stop this **WARNING** from appearing.

Answer (score 9):

You could try `-WarningAction Ignore`, but if that doesn't work, you can redirect the warning stream, which is stream 3, to `$null` (or to wherever you want):

```powershell
New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $storageName 3> $null
# Left out other parameters for readability
```

Note that `-Verbose:$false` will affect verbose messages, not warnings, which are a different stream.

[about_Redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx)

Also note that this requires Powershell 3+:

> The All (*), Warning (3), Verbose (4) and Debug (5) redirection
>   operators were introduced
>                               in Windows PowerShell 3.0. They do not work in earlier versions of Windows PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks! But how to put this in a readable form. Is there some inbuilt variable to get 3 (Warning stream). For a beginner, 3> $null would be new and difficult to understand! Please let me know if it make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking about putting it in a readable form.

Comment: Just include a comment explaining what the 3 means

Comment: I was responding to @PradebbanRaja

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem before and solve this by the follow:

```
New-AzureStorageAccount ... | Out-Null
```