# New-AzKeyVault - The provided information does not map to an AD object id

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to add a Keyvault with PowerShell. I am always getting below two warnings while creating this. Though the vault is getting created successfully but, but want to understand how can I elminiate this warnings?

```
New-AzKeyVault -VaultName  "kvxxxxxxxxxxx" `
        -ResourceGroupName "RG-xxxx" -Location "South Central US"

WARNING: The provided information does not map to an AD object id. 
WARNING: Access policy is not set. No user or application have access permission to use this vault. This can happen if the vault was created by  a service principal. Please use Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy to set access policies.
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034259/how-to-hide-warnings-from-azure-powershell-command-lets

Comment: Can you make sure the first WARNING was caused by this command? Have you run other commands together?

Comment: @JoyWang That was the only command

Comment: How did you login the `Az` powershell?

Comment: This is my msdn account, I used my hotmail account to login

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side. The two `WARNING`s were caused by your account is a `Personal Account/Microsoft account`(e.g. outlook, hotmail account) in your Azure AD tenant, your `user type` is `Guest`.

[image]

[image]

Actually you can just ignore them, or use the `-WarningAction Ignore` parameter as mentioned in the comment.

When using a work account/member user type to create a keyvault, it will add the account which used to create the keyvault to the access policy of the keyvault automatically. In your case, you could use the command [`Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/set-azkeyvaultaccesspolicy?view=azps-2.6.0) to set the access policy after creating the keyvault.